# Custom UIPickerview in ios7

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I'm new to the ios development world.

I'm developing a small application for my homework.

I'm trying to make a custom UIPickerview that when i click the text field it will appear,
then when i select the wanted data and hide it, the selection should appear in the text field.

i tried to follow this tutorial on youtube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HnNHG3zB48M
but i could not drag and drop from the story board to the .h file.
i though that i could not do it because the view controller that I'm working with is not the first view/page, am i right?
so i made another class with the same name as the view-controller I'm using and write it as a code, but how can i connect it with the inspector?

thanks...

Comment: Do you have an outlet declared for it?

Comment: 1. Did you use the single view application, as told in the episode before? 2. did you try to drag it to the .h file, or did you accidentially choose the .m file? 3. Do you drag it to the place after @interface and before @end?

Comment: yes i have declared an outlet

Comment: yes i'm using the single view app,

Comment: but it is not the first view in my app